# Windows 10 Technical Preview worst case scenario

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, multi-boot, hard-drive-recovery

I'm planning on installing Windows Technical Preview on a dual boot on my (gasp) primary Windows 8.1 laptop. Naturally, the repeated cautions relating to this pre-release software have made me paranoid that my laptop could throw a BSOD or something. The SSD in my ultrabook has a recovery partition (well, 3 actually, for some reason), and I have also created a USB recovery drive. All the files I care about are on OneDrive, and I've made a system restore point. The only other USB drive I have now has the ISO for the technical preview.

Should I be worried that I haven't also created a system image backup (control panel > file history > system image backup) on a USB drive? Or is that just overkill? As I understand it, a system image isn't much good without a recovery drive (and I can't have both as I don't have any more USB drives)?

Comment: A BSOD *should* be specific to the OS that's running at the time. I suspect the worst case scenario is issues with the *bootloader*. That said, I tend to like to have a system image backup or its third party equivilent in case of *hardware* failure.

Comment: Would a USB recovery drive likely be sufficient to repair an issue with the bootloader?

Comment: It might. Its *fairly* unlikely you'll malf up the bootloader badly enough that a windows recovery disk can't save it.